# SUPEE-6788 - Call to a member function `isTypeAllowed()` on a non-object

Tags: error, supee-6788

I have applied patch SUPEE-6788 but this breaks my store and generates an error:
Call to a member function `isTypeAllowed()` on a non-object in `Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php`

I have whitelisted all blocks and variables, but this problem still occurs.

I found out that replacing `Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` with code from before the patch solves the problem.

I can't find out how to track down the problem and solve this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If you check the Filter.php file after applying 6788 patch, you will find it is adding below bit of code.

```
if ($this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
   $type = $blockParameters['type'];
   $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
}
```

This `$this->_permissionBlock` is object of `Mage::getModel('admin/block');` model which is new settings added by this security patch. you can find this settings in admin.

```
Admin -> System -> Permission -> Blocks
```

Check if this settings are exist in your system. Check class `Mage_Admin_Model_Block` exist in your system or not.

Comment: Hi akhilesh. I found out that the problem was within an extension that should be updated. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you can't update the extension, replacing

```
if ($this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
   $type = $blockParameters['type'];
   $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
}
```

with

```
if (gettype($this->_permissionBlock) == 'object' && $this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
   $type = $blockParameters['type'];
   $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
}
```

should work...

All this does is ensure that the "permission block" is an object before trying to run its member function.